# Sorting varchar column as numeric in mysql with null value as the bottom

Tags: mysql, sorting, numeric, varchar

i am trying to sort a column in the mysql query which is of type varchar but has may/maynot have numeric values.

```
for example it may have the values

2012-10
2012-41
2012-1

which should be sorted as follows:
2012-1
2012-10
2012-41

but if the values are :
M-1
M-13
M-5

it should be sorted as :
M-1
M-5
M-13

and if null values are present it should be last.
```

Dont know if it is possible. Please Help

Comment: You just want to sort numerically by the number after the hyphen?

Comment: no.. like in the 1st type there can be value 2013-12 also which mst come after the 2012 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a numeric sort by the number after the hyphen, use this:

```
ORDER BY column IS NOT NULL, SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', 1), CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', 2) AS DECIMAL)
```

`column IS NOT NULL` sorts the null columns last, the `CAST()` expression sorts the rest by the number.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. bt i need to sort it with the 1st part aswell.. i dont think this will work in that case.

Comment: I added another clause to order by the part before the hyphen as well. You didn't say that in the question.